# how to use react and node to upload string as file to google drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

how to use react js as frontend and node js as backend to upload / read files from google drive.

This is what I already tried : [Write string as text file then upload to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860664/write-string-as-text-file-then-upload-to-google-drive)

Is it possible to upload files using react?

If not, then I would like to send a string from react to node and then upload to google drive

Comment: If you are facing problems on access tokens please let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below approach and worked for me. (As of now I am uploading file from frontend (vueJS) only). I am assuming you have google client id & client secret & refresh & access tokens.

NOTE::: When user uploads any file I am storing those files inside my google drive. Every time without logging into my account I am getting access_token by following some steps and accessing my google drive without logging in(No need of OAuth. ).

**front end code VueJs** (html code is same for all frameworks) you have to get code for file uploading through input in react almost similar to this

```
data:{
   file:''
}

<label>Files
    <input type="file" id="files" ref="file"  v-on:change="handleFilesUpload()"/> // here you can write corresponding react code for file uploading
  </label>
  <button v-on:click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
```

**On submit methods **

```
handleFilesUpload() {
        console.log("helloWorld");
        // this.files = this.$refs.files.files;
        this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
        console.log("file is ");
        console.log(this.file);
 }

  submitFiles() {
        // for storing file data
        let formData1 = new FormData();
        formData1.append('file',this.file); // here this.file is data when user browses through input button data will be stored to **file**
```

Now you have entire file stored in **formData1**. Now you have to send this data to googledriveapi through api calls(I was using axios)

**API call**

```
uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(formData1) {
     return axios({
        url:'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/related;boundary=9700883396bond',
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

        },

        formData1

    })
}
```

Now If you go to your google drive you can see one file which is newly created. Following links might help.

[sample script uploading to google drive](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/bd53b366aedef70e35a35f449c51eced)